# PL/SQL trigger for after insert, update, delete that enters Data into Log Table with a Sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am working on a homework problem.  I am running into compilation issues with my trigger and am having trouble understanding how to create a trigger that references a sequence and another table, and insert those values into a log table that I've created. [I have read that using SERIAL not null on the Table column entry may eliminates the need for a sequence and referencing table](http://www.dbforums.com/informix/1628545-create-sequence-create-trigger.html), but I need that for my homework to work.

I need some help figuring out how to get my trigger to compile.  It is having problems with my Bind Variables :NEW from the sequence, and also the idpay value inserted from another Table.  I'm not sure if my declarations are correct and the first two statements after the BEGIN statement are correct as that 1st line was flagged as a compilation error.  [I think something is going on with this example and my lack of the NULL value entry there in the IF statement, but unsure where to put that part in my coding.](http://www.razorsql.com/features/oracle_add_sequence_trigger.html)

And of course the [Oracle 11g Reference Doc for Triggers, I've gone over it but you can check it out yourself too.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#)

Here is the setup question: 
1.  Use the Donations database. The organization wants to track all pledge payment
activity. Each time a pledge payment is added, changed, or removed, the following 
information should be captured in a separate table: username, current date, action
taken (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE), and the idpay value for the payment record.

Create a table named DD_PAYTRACK to hold this information. Include a primary key column
to be populated by a sequence, and create new sequence named DD_PTRACK_SEQ for the
primary key column.

Create a single trigger for recording the requested information to track pledge 
payment activity, and test the trigger for all action types for idpay=1470. 
Display the records from the DD_PAYTRACK table by using SELECT statement.

```
select * from dd_paytrack;

IDTRACK    PTUSER        PTDATE       PTACTION       PTPAYID                
4          AAX5367E220   10-DEC-12     INSERT        1470                   
5          AAX5367E220   10-DEC-12     UPDATE            1470                   
6          AAX5367E220   10-DEC-12     DELETE        1470
```

Here is what I've done so far, even after adding these Insert, Update, and Delete statements, it's still returning an Empty table, but because of the answer below I have fixed what was suggested.

****I fixed it, I had to add my own Update, Insert, and Delete statements after compiling the Trigger.  Works great now.  Thanks Noel!!!****

```
    DROP TABLE dd_paytrack;
    DROP SEQUENCE idtrack_seq;

    CREATE TABLE dd_paytrack(
    idtrack         NUMBER,
    pt_user         VARCHAR2(30),
    pt_date         DATE,
    pt_action       VARCHAR2(30),
    pt_payid        NUMBER(6,0),
    CONSTRAINT pk_dd_paytrack PRIMARY KEY (idtrack)
    );

    CREATE SEQUENCE idtrack_seq;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pledge_pay_trigger
      AFTER 
        INSERT OR 
        UPDATE OR 
        DELETE 
      ON dd_payment
      FOR EACH ROW  
    DECLARE
      log_action  dd_paytrack.pt_action%TYPE; 
      id_pay      dd_paytrack.pt_payid%TYPE;    
    BEGIN
    id_pay := :NEW.idpay;
    IF INSERTING THEN
    log_action := 'Insert';
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    log_action := 'Update';
    ELSIF DELETING THEN
    id_pay := :OLD.idpay;
    log_action := 'Delete';
    ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This code is not reachable.');
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO dd_paytrack (idtrack, pt_user, pt_date, pt_action, pt_payid)
      VALUES(idtrack_seq.NEXTVAL, USER, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY'), log_action,      
    id_pay);

    END pledge_pay_trigger;
    /

   INSERT INTO dd_payment(idpay, idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod)
    VALUES (1470, 105, 250, SYSDATE, 'CC');
    commit;  

    UPDATE dd_payment
    SET payamt = 25
    WHERE idpay = 1470;
    commit;

    UPDATE dd_payment 
    SET payamt = 2000
    WHERE idpay = 1470;
    COMMIT;

    DELETE 
    FROM dd_payment
    WHERE idpay = 1470;
    COMMIT;


    SET serveroutput ON
    select * from dd_paytrack;
```

Here is the Donation Table Scheme which it references the dd_paytrack Table for my Homework problem.  I tested it and this schema seems to work okay after cutting and pasting it.

```
-- The DoGood Donor Database 
-- A donor, who represents a person or company that has committed to make a donation to             
the DoGood organzation. 

DROP TABLE dd_donor CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE dd_project CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE dd_status CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE dd_pledge CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE dd_payment CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE DD_Donor (
    idDonor number(4),
    Firstname varchar2(15),
    Lastname varchar2(30),
                  Typecode CHAR(1),
    Street varchar2(40),
    City varchar2(20),
    State char(2),
    Zip varchar2(9),
    Phone varchar2(10),
    Fax varchar2(10),
    Email varchar2(25),
                  News char(1),
    dtentered date DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    CONSTRAINT donor_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idDonor) );
CREATE TABLE DD_Project (
                   idProj number(6),
                   Projname varchar2(60),
                   Projstartdate DATE,
                   Projenddate DATE,
                   Projfundgoal number(12,2),
                   ProjCoord varchar2(20),
                   CONSTRAINT project_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idProj),
                   CONSTRAINT project_name_uk  UNIQUE (Projname)  );      
CREATE TABLE DD_Status (
                   idStatus number(2),
                   Statusdesc varchar2(15),
                   CONSTRAINT status_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idStatus) );     
CREATE TABLE DD_Pledge (
                   idPledge number(5),
                   idDonor number(4),
                   Pledgedate DATE,
                   Pledgeamt number(8,2),
                   idProj number(5),
                   idStatus number(2),
                   Writeoff number(8,2),
                   paymonths number(3),
                   Campaign number(4),
                   Firstpledge char(1),
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idPledge),
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_idDonor_fk FOREIGN KEY (idDonor)
                           REFERENCES dd_donor (idDonor), 
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_idProj_fk FOREIGN KEY (idProj)
                           REFERENCES dd_project (idProj),
                   CONSTRAINT pledge_idStatus_fk FOREIGN KEY (idStatus)
                           REFERENCES dd_status (idStatus));                   
CREATE TABLE DD_Payment (
                   idPay number(6),
                   idPledge number(5),
                   Payamt number(8,2),
                   Paydate DATE,
                   Paymethod char(2),
                   CONSTRAINT payment_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idPay),
                   CONSTRAINT pay_idpledge_fk FOREIGN KEY (idPledge)
                           REFERENCES dd_pledge (idPledge) );                   
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (301, 'Mary', 'Treanor', 'I','243 main St.', 'Norfolk',     
'VA','23510',NULL,NULL,'mtrea492@mdv.com','Y','01-SEP-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (302, 'Patrick', 'Lee', 'I','11 Hooper St.', 'Norfolk',     
'VA','23510','7572115445',NULL,'pleeNorf@gmail.com','N','09-SEP-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (303, 'Terry', 'Venor', 'I','556 Loop Lane.', 'Chesapeake', 
'VA','23320',NULL,NULL,'tervenr@drw.edu','Y','18-SEP-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (304, 'Sherry', 'Pane', 'I','Center Blvd.', 'Virginia Beach', 
'VA','23455',NULL,NULL,'toppane@yahoo.com','Y','21-SEP-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (305, 'Thomas', 'Sheer', 'I','66 Train St.', 'Chesapeake', 
'VA','23322','7579390022',NULL,'tls3488@sheer.com','Y','01-MAR-2013');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (306, NULL, 'Coastal Developers', 'B','3667 Shore Dr.', 'Virginia Beach', 
'VA','23450','8889220004',NULL,'coastVA@cdev.com','Y','30-SEP-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (307, NULL, 'VA Community Org', 'G','689 Bush Dr.', 'Norfolk', 
'VA','23513','7578337467','7578337468','vacmorg@biz.com','Y','03-OCT-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (308, 'Betty', 'Konklin', 'I','11 Shark Ln.', 'Virginia Beach', 
'VA','23455','7574550087',NULL,'shark11@cox.net','N','04-OCT-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (309, 'Jim', 'Tapp', 'I','200 Pine Tree Blvd.', 'Chesapeake', 
'VA','23320','',NULL,'','N','08-OCT-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_donor  
  VALUES (310, NULL, 'Unique Dezigns', 'B','Connect Circle Unit 12', 'Chesapeake', 
'VA','23320','7574442121',NULL,'UDezigns@cox.net','Y','11-SEP-2012');
INSERT INTO dd_project
  VALUES (500,'Elders Assistance League', '01-SEP-2012','31-OCT-2012',15000,'Shawn 
Hasee');
INSERT INTO dd_project
  VALUES (501,'Community food pantry #21 freezer equipment', '01-OCT-2012','31-DEC-
2012',65000,'Shawn Hasee');
INSERT INTO dd_project
  VALUES (502,'Lang Scholarship Fund', '01-JAN-2013','01-NOV-2013',100000,'Traci 
Brown');
INSERT INTO dd_project
  VALUES (503,'Animal shelter Vet Connect Program', '01-DEC-2012','30-MAR-
2013',25000,'Traci Brown');
INSERT INTO dd_project
  VALUES (504,'Shelter Share Project 2013', '01-FEB-2013','31-JUL-2013',35000,'Traci 
Brown');
INSERT INTO dd_status
  VALUES (10,'Open');
INSERT INTO dd_status
  VALUES (20,'Complete');
INSERT INTO dd_status
  VALUES (30,'Overdue');
INSERT INTO dd_status
  VALUES (40,'Closed');
INSERT INTO dd_status
  VALUES (50,'Hold');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (100,303,'18-SEP-2012',80,500,20,NULL,0,738,'Y');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (101,304,'21-SEP-2012',35,500,20,NULL,0,738,'Y');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (102,310,'01-OCT-2012',500,501,20,NULL,0,749,'Y');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (103,307,'03-OCT-2012',2000,501,20,NULL,0,749,'N');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (104,308,'04-OCT-2012',240,501,10,NULL,12,749,'Y');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (105,309,'08-OCT-2012',120,501,10,NULL,12,749,'Y');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (106,301,'12-OCT-2012',75,500,20,NULL,0,738,'N');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (107,302,'15-OCT-2012',1200,501,10,NULL,24,749,'Y');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (108,308,'20-JAN-2013',480,503,10,NULL,24,790,'N');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (109,301,'01-FEB-2013',360,503,10,NULL,12,790,'N');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (110,303,'01-MAR-2013',300,504,10,NULL,12,756,'N');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (111,306,'01-MAR-2013',1500,504,20,NULL,0,756,'Y');
INSERT INTO dd_pledge
   VALUES (112,309,'16-MAR-2013',240,504,10,NULL,12,756,'N');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1425,100,80,'18-SEP-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1426,101,35,'21-SEP-2012','DC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1427,102,500,'01-OCT-2012','CH');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1428,103,2000,'03-OCT-2012','CH');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1429,106,75,'12-OCT-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1430,104,20,'01-NOV-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1431,105,10,'01-NOV-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1432,107,50,'01-NOV-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1433,104,20,'01-DEC-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1434,105,10,'01-DEC-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
  VALUES (1435,107,50,'01-DEC-2012','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1436,104,20,'01-JAN-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1437,105,10,'01-JAN-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1438,107,50,'01-JAN-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1439,104,20,'01-FEB-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1440,105,10,'01-FEB-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1441,107,50,'01-FEB-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1442,108,20,'01-FEB-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1443,109,30,'01-FEB-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1444,104,20,'01-MAR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1445,105,10,'01-MAR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1446,107,50,'01-MAR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1447,108,20,'01-MAR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1448,109,30,'01-MAR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1449,110,25,'01-MAR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1450,111,1500,'01-MAR-2013','CH');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1451,104,20,'01-APR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1452,105,10,'01-APR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1453,107,50,'01-APR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1454,108,20,'01-APR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1455,109,30,'01-APR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1456,110,25,'01-APR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1457,112,20,'01-APR-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1458,104,20,'01-MAY-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1459,105,10,'01-MAY-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1460,107,50,'01-MAY-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1461,108,20,'01-MAY-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1462,109,30,'01-MAY-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1463,110,25,'01-MAY-2013','CC');
INSERT INTO dd_payment
   VALUES (1464,112,20,'01-MAY-2013','CC');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the sequence value in the insert statement,

```
   INSERT INTO dd_paytrack
           (idtrack, pt_user, pt_date,
            pt_action, pt_payid
           )
    VALUES (idtrack_seq.NEXTVAL, USER, TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY'),
            log_action, id_pay
           );
```

there is no need to select it as below.

```
SELECT idtrack_seq.NEXTVAL
 INTO :NEW.idtrack
 FROM DUAL;
```

Also, you have missed a colon in this line,

```
      id_pay := :OLD.idpay;
```

EDIT: One more thing, there is no point in having DBMS_OUTPUT statement in the trigger. Since you wont see it, even if the execution reaches it.

Comment: I have fixed the errors, but my select query returns an Empty table now.  I will edit my code above to reflect this change.  Thank you for your help.  Not sure why it's an empty table now with these edits.  I included the Set Serveroutput ON

Comment: @meachamrob Are you sure you used the correct where clause? I dont see payment id 1470 in the insert statements.

Comment: You are correct, looking through the data shows no statements for 1470, I guess I have to create those insert, update, and delete  statements myself.  The Professor didn't explain that part too well

Comment: Thanks It works now after adding those insert, delete, and update statements.  I appreciate your quick response to my question and your time today.

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL trigger for after insert, update, delete that enters Data into Log Table with a Sequence

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pledge_pay_trigger2
      AFTER 
        INSERT OR 
        UPDATE OR 
        DELETE 
      ON dd_payment
      FOR EACH ROW  
    DECLARE
      log_action  dd_payment2.pt_action%TYPE; 
      id_pay      dd_payment2.idpay%TYPE;    
      id_Pledge   dd_payment2.idPledge%TYPE;    
      Pay_amt     dd_payment2.Payamt%TYPE;    
      Pay_date    dd_payment2.Paydate%TYPE;    
      Pay_method  dd_payment2.Paymethod%TYPE;    

BEGIN
id_pay := :NEW.idpay;
id_Pledge   := :NEW.IDPLEDGE;
Pay_amt     := :NEW.PAYAMT;
Pay_date    := :NEW.PAYDATE;
Pay_method  := :NEW.PAYMETHOD;
IF INSERTING THEN
  log_action := 'Insert';
   INSERT INTO dd_payment2(idpay, idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod,pt_action)
    VALUES (id_pay, id_Pledge, Pay_amt, TO_CHAR(Pay_date, 'DD-MON-YY'), Pay_method,log_action);
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
  log_action := 'Update';
  UPDATE DD_PAYMENT2 SET PAYAMT=Pay_amt,PAYDATE=TO_CHAR(Pay_date, 'DD-MON-YY'),pt_action='UPDATE' WHERE idpay=id_pay;
ELSIF DELETING THEN
id_pay := :OLD.idpay;
log_action := 'Delete';
UPDATE DD_PAYMENT2 SET pt_action='DELETE' WHERE idpay=id_pay;        
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This code is not reachable.');
END IF;
END pledge_pay_trigger2;
/

COMMIT;

//    if log_action ='Insert' then
       INSERT INTO dd_payment2(idpay, idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod,pt_action)
        VALUES (id_pay, id_Pledge, Pay_amt, TO_CHAR(Pay_date, 'DD-MON-YY'), Pay_method,log_action);
    else if log_action ='Update' then
      UPDATE DD_PAYMENT2 SET PAYAMT=Pay_amt,PAYDATE=TO_CHAR(Pay_date, 'DD-MON-YY'),pt_action='UPDATE' WHERE idpay=id_pay;
    else
      UPDATE DD_PAYMENT2 SET pt_action='DELETE' WHERE idpay=id_pay;        
    end if


     ALTER TABLE DD_PAYMENT2 ADD pt_action VARCHAR2(30 BYTE);

     COMMIT;


        INSERT INTO dd_payment(idpay, idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod)
    VALUES (1470, 105, 250, SYSDATE, 'CC');
    commit;  



         UPDATE dd_payment 
    SET payamt = 2000
    WHERE idpay = 1470;
    COMMIT;

        DELETE 
    FROM dd_payment
    WHERE idpay = 1470;
    COMMIT;
```