# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" Need help finding cause of error pl/sql

Tags: plsql, pls-00103

I hate doing this but my SQL is weak that I'm not able to troubleshoot using the error message to correct the syntax. Can someone help check my syntax and see what is causing the error? I thinking it has something to do with the DECLARE and BEGIN. Maybe I should remove the Declare?

The error I am getting is `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or lik`

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or lik <BR>
```

My syntax to create a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger emp_dept_briu 
instead of insert or update on emp_dept_v 
referencing new as n   
         old as o 
for each row 
declare 
l_deptno emp.deptno%type; 
begin 
case  
when inserting  
   insert into emp 
     ( empno, ename , deptno) 
   values 
     ( :n.empno, :n.ename, :n.deptno ) 
   ; 
   insert into dept 
     ( deptno, dname ) 
   values 
     ( :n.deptno, :n.dname ) 
   ; 
 when updating  
   update emp 
   set ename = :n.ename 
   ,   deptno = :n.deptno 
   where empno = :n.empno 
   ; 
   update dept 
   set dname = :n.dname 
   where deptno = :n.deptno 
   ; 
 else    
   null 
   ; 
end case 
; 
end 
;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214107/pl-sql-trigger-for-after-insert-update-delete-that-enters-data-into-log-table

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is simply wrong. That's all

```
CASE

   WHEN INSERTING THEN 
       INSERT INTO ...;
       INSERT INTO ...;
   WHEN UPDATING THEN 
       UPDATE ...;
   ELSE NULL;

END;
```

But I would recommend you go for

```
IF INSERTING THEN
   ...;
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
   ...;
ELSE
   NULL;
END IF;
```

Comment: Okay, let me try. I copied it from a blog someone wrote and someone had the same question but it didn't get answered. Let me try and let you know. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Cool, got it to work. Thanks @nexus.

```
create or replace trigger emp_dept_briu
instead of insert or update on emp_dept_v 
referencing new as n   
     old as o
for each row 
declare 
l_deptno emp.deptno%type; 
begin
CASE
when inserting THEN 
insert into emp 
 ( empno, ename , deptno) 
values 
 ( :n.empno, :n.ename, :n.deptno ) 
; 
insert into dept 
 ( deptno, dname ) 
values 
 ( :n.deptno, :n.dname ) 
; 
when updating THEN 
update emp 
set ename = :n.ename 
,   deptno = :n.deptno 
where empno = :n.empno 
; 
update dept 
set dname = :n.dname 
where deptno = :n.deptno 
; 
else    
null
; 
end case;
end;
```